Detecta un espacio vacío en mi registro y no tengo idea del porque
Estoy recién aprendiendo PHP y estaba haciendo un registro cuando de la nada me empezó a detectar un espacio vacío.
Aquí el código de registro, espero me puedan decir como lo puedo solucionar.
<?php

if (!empty($_POST["btnregister"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["nomrbe"]) & !empty($_POST["apellido"]) & !empty($_POST["fecha"]) & !empty($_POST["dni"]) & !empty($_POST["correo"])) {
        
        $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
        $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
        $fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
        $dni=$_POST["dni"];
        $correo=$_POST["correo"];
        
        $sql=$conexion->query("insert into usuarios('nombre','apellido','fecha_de_nacimiento','dni','correo') VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$fecha','$dni','$correo')");
        if ($sql==1) {
            echo '<div class alert alert-success>"usuario registrado efectuivamente" </div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class alert alert-danger>"error al intentar registrar al usuario" </div>';
        }
        
    } else {
        echo '<div class=alert alert-warning>"algun campo esta vacio"</div>';
    }
    
}
?>


que es o que significa un espacio vacio... no logro persivir lo que tienes entre las manos ...

ha te reocmiendo hacer el [tour]

Que error te da exactamente, puedes ponerlo? Y en un lado evalúas nomrbe y en la query tienes nombre. Pueda que por ahí ande la cosa...

Me parece que el error esta en esta línea:
if (!empty($_POST["nomrbe"]) & !empty($_POST["apellido"]) 
& !empty($_POST["fecha"]) & !empty($_POST["dni"]) 
& !empty($_POST["correo"])) {

Hay dos problemas aquí:
Estás usando & para verificar si todos los campos están llenos. Deberías usar && para la operación lógica AND.
Estás verificando campos como nomrbe, apellido, fecha, dni, y correo, pero en realidad, parece que estos campos se llaman nombre, apellido, fecha, dni, y correo.
La solución sería algo asi:
if (!empty($_POST["nombre"]) && !empty($_POST["apellido"]) 
&& !empty($_POST["fecha"]) && !empty($_POST["dni"]) 
&& !empty($_POST["correo"])) {

También creo que no deberías validar !empty($_POST["btnregister"]) dado que como es un componente Boton no le encuentro la lógica para ser validado.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
